# Rails Form Not Saving With Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So I made a form to create "comments" on my "projects". I had it working fine but decided to implement ajax via info from Railscasts. Now the form seems to submit but its contents do not save in my database. I am trying to get the comment form to submit and then re-render the comments. Thanks!

**My terminal output:**

```
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"content"=>"Cat dog"}, "commit"=>"Post", "project_id"=>"29"}
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC  LIMIT 1
Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 29]]
Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"  WHERE "comments"."project_id" = ? LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0  [["project_id", 29]]
Rendered collection (0.0ms)
Rendered comments/create.js.erb (1.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 44ms (Views: 40.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

**Comments Create Form:**

```
<%= form_for([@project, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Comment...?" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**Comments Controller**

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @comment = @project.comments.build(comment_params.merge(
        :user_id => current_user.id))
    @comments = @project.comments.paginate(page: params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
            format.html { redirect_to project_url(@project) }
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

**create.js**

```
$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@comments)) %>");
$('#new-comment').remove();
$('#add-comment').show();
```

**Addiitonal HTML**

```
<div>
    <% if @project.comments.any? %>
        <h4>Comments (<%= @project.comments.count %>)</h4>
        <ol class="comments">
            <%= render @comments %>
        </ol>
        <%= will_paginate @comments %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Which line of code is supposed to save the comment? I see a `build` but no `save`.

Comment: You're totally right! So if I add @comment.save right after the '@comments', I have the form saving but still not refreshing the list of comments ajax-style. Am I putting that in the correct place?

Comment: I would put it right after `build` or change `build` to `create`.

Comment: So I added a `create` to the code and now it is inserting into the DB (thank you!) but it still isn't refreshing the comments displayed via ajax afterwards. Any thoughts? I added some 'additional html' here that may be relevant.

Comment: If you want to select a class, you should use `$('.comments')` not `$('#comments')`.

Comment: Thanks, you just saved me hours. All systems are go. You're a champ!